# SVN committing and merging older revision

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is there a way in which after i update my branch to the revision i want-older- to commit it and merge to trunk?

I tried: `svn update -r REV` where the REV is the previous revision number and that worked great but how to i merge from my branch to trunk?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is no different from the normal merge from branch to trunk.  TortoiseSVN has a [Re-integrate a branch option](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html).